# Add Archtypes to Eclipse

Tags: maven, archetypes

I am new to MAVEN and restful services. I have MAVEN installed it correctly and set the variables. I was creating a webservice using the jersey-quickstart-webapp but found it did not appeared in the list of Archetypes. 
I tried to add it using using ADD Archetypes option. After the entering the details

```
GroupId: org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes
ArtifactId:  jersey-quickstart-webapp
Version : 2.16  // version is correct??

I get following error please help. 

<b>
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Could not resolve artifact 
org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes:jersey-quickstart-webapp:pom:2.16</b>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a ready explanation as to why the Eclipse archetype plugin was giving you this error, since `2.16` is a valid version of `jersey-quickstart-webapp`.  However, I would recommend that you try manually executing the following command from a command prompt:

```
mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeArtifactId=jersey-quickstart-webapp
    -DarchetypeGroupId=org.glassfish.jersey.archetypes -DinteractiveMode=false
    -DgroupId=com.example -DartifactId=simple-service-webapp -Dpackage=com.example
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.19
```

Make sure that you first delete the `jersey-quickstart-webapp` folder, if it exists, from your Maven `.m2` directory.  This may be necessary to avoid from something getting corrupted during the archetype install.

Here is a [link to the official documentation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/getting-started.html#new-webapp) for creating a Jersey EE application from a Maven archetype.

Comment: Thanks a LOT. This is working now..... The jersey-quickstart-webapp archetype appears in the list of archetypes now.   I am just afraid that I dont have to do this for all further archetypes in future . Anyways the problem is solved for now......Thanks a lot.